# SSRS: Concatenate field's distinct values

Tags: reporting-services, expression, reportviewer

How can I concatenate distinct values under a column in a dataset, and display the result in a table or textbox? For example:

Dataset:

```
+----+------+
| ID | Pet  |
+----+------+
| 1  | Cat  |
+----+------+
| 2  | Dog  |
+----+------+
| 3  | Frog |
+----+------+
| 4  | Dog  |
+----+------+
```

Result:

```
+-----+----------------+
| Pet | Cat, Dog, Frog |
+-----+----------------+
```

All I have found online is using the Join + LookUpSet. I found [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2f27910a-63d8-4ccd-8181-2ef304388fb5/ssrs-concatenate-field-in-one-string-delimited-by-comma-without-sql?forum=sqlreportingservices) and tried:

```
=Join(LookUpSet(Fields!Pet.Value, Fields!Pet.Value, Fields!Pet.Value, "PetsDS"), ", ")
```

However, it only gives me the first item.

Comment: Any reason not to do it in SQL - thats easy. What version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: Apparently `=Join(LookupSet(1,1,Fields!Pet.Value, "DatasetName"),", ")` should work - except that it won't remove duplicated. I think you'll need to do that in SQL.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I use the ReportViewer (version 12.0) on Visual Studio 15. I decided to just use SQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use query like below to see whether it works or not

```
create table #jj  (name varchar(20), id int)

insert into #jj values ('a', 1), ('s',2),('d',3),('a',4)
  SELECT STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' +name FROM #jj FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as [Currency]
```

[image]

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue of duplicates which already exist in the data.

Comment: @DaleBurrell this actually worked for me. It did remove the duplicates. Thanks!